# Extracting number from inside parentheses in column list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column of lists and want to extract numbers from list strings and add them to their own separate column.

```
     Column A 
 0      [ FUNNY (1),  CARING (1)]
 1      [ Gives good feedback (17),  Clear communicator (2)]
 2      [ CARING (3),  Gives good feedback (3)]
 3      [ FUNNY (2),  Clear communicator (1)]
 4                                         []
 5                                         []
 6      [ CARING (1),  Clear communicator (1)]
```

I would like the output to look as follows:

```
FUNNY     CARING    Gives good feedback    Clear communicator
  1          1            None                   None
  None       None         17                     2
  None       3            3                      None
  2          None         None                   1
  None       None         None                   None
```

etc...

Comment: I'd string split into two columns by `,`, then use regex to match `\d` or `\d+` (whichever fits all your cases.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but the problem is the lists are not uniformly ordered (e.g., "Funny" would be in column 1 & 2 in this case) and are actually up to 17 items long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `apply` with `pd.Series`, then `extract` and reshape with `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df['Column A'].apply(pd.Series).stack().str.extract(r'(\w+)\((\d+)', expand=True)\
              .reset_index(1, drop=True).set_index(0, append=True)[1]\
              .unstack(1)
```

Output:

```
0 Authentic Caring Classy Funny
0         1      3   None     2
1         2   None      1     2
```

## Edit with new input data set:

```
df['Column A'].apply(pd.Series).stack().str.extract(r'(\w+).*\((\d+)', expand=True)\
              .reset_index(1, drop=True)\
              .set_index(0, append=True)[1]\
              .unstack(1)

0 CARING Clear FUNNY Gives
0      1  None     1  None
1   None     2  None    17
2      3  None  None     3
3   None     1     2  None
6      1     1  None  None
```

Comment: That worked beautifully for the example I gave but is giving me the following error for my data. "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". I've revised the question.

Comment: @KellyG it worked for me with the same data set..I had to modify the extract statement a little bit.